# Why does an XPM page keep posting to GetListPublishedTo?

Tags: experience-manager

I can see in the browser logs of our XPM pages that GetListPublishedTo gets repeatedly called. I can understand that it would get called once, but in the absence of a good reason, this looks like a symptom of something wrong. (In any case, I'm analysing slow loading of the pages, and every little helps.)

Why would the page need to call this repeatedly? What sort of problem could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about it, but I believe it will regularly call this for all of the Components on the Page (and the Page itself) in order to know when they were last published. This is likely to show the correct borders and enable options for saving and publishing (e.g. Update View).

So I would not automatically consider that a sign that something is broken.